# Windows Scipt to disable minimize and maximize buttons

Tags: windows, vbscript

I found the following vbs script that will open IE perfectly the way I would like. I've seen some javascript for a webpage to disable the min/max buttons, but doesnt really work seemlessly.

I'm on XP Pro.

Is there any way to edit this to disable the min/max buttons in a application window?

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With oIE
 .FullScreen = True   
 .AddressBar = False   
 .ToolBar = True  
 .StatusBar = True   
 .Navigate("www.google.com")   
 .Visible = True
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run the browser in kiosk mode. Start `iexplore` with the `-k` option.

This won't disable the minimize buttons. There is no way to do that without writing your own browser, but you don't see the minimize buttons either. It is essentially full-screen. To exit kiosk mode, type <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>

See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780

Comment: This would work perfectly if I could get a way to have the address bar, ctrl+l or +o wont work.

Comment: Ctrl-O works for me (Iexplore 10 on Win7) (opens a window that asks for the address to open)